# Question about sequence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $N_0\in \mathbb{N}.$ If a sequence of complex numbers $\{F_N\}_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ has the following properties:
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} |F_N|^{1/N}=0$$ and for all $N \geq N_0$,
$$|F_N|\leq N\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} |F_k|,\quad \quad \quad  $$
then there exists $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $F_N=0$ for all $N \geq N_1.$

I would like to know if this is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let's try $F_{N} = \frac{1}{(N-1)!}$.
Clearly Nth root of $F_N$ tends to $0$.
Also $$N*(\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}F_{k}) > N*(F_{N+1})= N*\frac{1}{N!} = F_{N}$$